# Create table of unique values from join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with various addresses. One is a table of locations we already have on file, the other is new business. The idea is that I'm joining these two tables on their co-ordinates in order to show if we have a clash between the new business and the current business.

What I have found is that in the new business we have one location that matches three locations that we already have.

When I do my simple inner join I get back 3 records when really I want to display the 4 (1 from new, 3 from current). I have tried other joins and union as well as sub queries but with no luck. I know there is a way but just can't figure it out.

```
SELECT *
FROM NewBusiness
INNER JOIN Live L ON N.Latitude = L.Latitude AND N.Longitude = L.Longitude
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add sample data and expected result, for me it is not clear what are you trying to achieve and how data is structured in the tables.

Comment: Please add data and expected result to better understand the issue.

Comment: happy to but not sure how I post sample data. I can say that the column structure in both tables are exactly the same. Which is why I'm trying to get a table with unique records. So at the moment I have three records from my Live table 1 matching from my New Business table. When I INNER Join I get three records but a duplication of the columns going from left to right and my New Business location is duplicated three times. What I really want to see is four records with a unique set of columns.

Comment: Check out this link to know more on how to add sample data:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/  and also to improve question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best answer (it catch duplicate rows in the same table) but still working correctly

```
select distinct 'oldbiz', l.id, l.latitude, l.longitude
  from Live l, NewBusiness n
 where l.latitude = n.latitude
  and l.longitude = n.longitude
union all
select distinct 'newbiz', n.id, n.latitude, n.longitude
 from Live l, NewBusiness n
where l.latitude = n.latitude
  and l.longitude = n.longitude
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d7f88/9)

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get what I think you are looking for using a union. It may not be the best way to do it but it looks like it works. I made a SQL Fiddle to show it.

You can see the fiddle here: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d7f88/1/0)

to test, I created two tables, Live and NewBusiness.
Created them like this

```
CREATE TABLE Live
    ([ID] varchar(1), [latitude] int, [longitude] int)
;

INSERT INTO Live
    ([ID], [latitude], [longitude])
VALUES
    ('a', 1, 2),
    ('b', 1, 2),
    ('c', 1, 2),
    ('d', 4, 3),
    ('e', 5, 4),
    ('k', 5, 7),
    ('l', 5, 9),
    ('M', 5, 7)
;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE NewBusiness
    ([ID] varchar(1), [latitude] int, [longitude] int)
;

INSERT INTO NewBusiness
    ([ID], [latitude], [longitude])
VALUES
    ('f', 1, 2),
    ('g', 5, 2),
    ('h', 1, 8),
    ('i', 6, 3),
    ('z', 5, 7),
    ('y', 12, 4),
    ('x', 5, 7)
;
```

The query I used was

```
 (    
   SELECT L.ID
           ,L.Latitude
           ,L.Longitude

    FROM Live L
    INNER JOIN NEWBUSINESS N 
    ON L.Latitude = N.Latitude AND L.Longitude = N.Longitude
 )
 UNION
 (
   SELECT N.ID 
           ,N.LATITUDE 
           ,N.LONGITUDE 
    FROM NEWBUSINESS N
    INNER JOIN Live L 
    ON N.Latitude = L.Latitude AND N.Longitude = L.Longitude
    GROUP BY N.ID
            ,N.LATITUDE
            ,N.LONGITUDE 
   )
```

The first part of the union gets all the things in Live that have matches in Newbusiness. The second part of the union gets all the things in Newbusiness that have matches in Live. The results are then union'd together.

Tables:

```
Live 
ID  latitude    longitude
a   1   2
b   1   2
c   1   2
d   4   3
e   5   4
k   5   7
l   5   9
M   5   7

**NewBusiness**
ID  latitude    longitude
f   1   2
g   5   2
h   1   8
i   6   3
z   5   7
y   12  4
x   5   7

**Query Results**
ID  Latitude    Longitude
a   1   2
b   1   2
c   1   2
f   1   2
k   5   7
M   5   7
x   5   7
z   5   7
```

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this give you what you need (it will count once for each record in either table that has a match in the other table):

```
WITH cte1
AS
(
    SELECT
        N.latitude
        , N.longitude
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N.latitude, N.longitude) r1
    FROM NewBusiness N
)
,

cte2
AS
(
    SELECT
        N.latitude
        , N.longitude
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY N.r1 ORDER BY N.latitude, N.longitude) r2
    FROM
        cte1 N
        JOIN Live L ON
            N.Latitude = L.Latitude
            AND N.Longitude = L.Longitude
)

SELECT
    latitude
    , longitude
    , 'NewBusiness' sourceTable
FROM cte2
WHERE r2 = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
    latitude
    , longitude
    , sourceTable
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            latitude
            , longitude
            , r2
            , 'Live' sourceTable
        FROM cte2
    ) Q
```